# MS-ACCESS Derived transform query from saved query does not recognize fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have a the following as saved query "qGetClubPoints"

```
SELECT t1.[season], t1.evIndex, t1.Category, t1.runner, 
   t1.runnerName, t1.ClubID, t1.ClubPoints, t2.CategoryGroupID 
FROM 
    League AS t1 INNER JOIN 
    [Categories] AS t2 
    ON t1.category = t2.category 
WHERE  
    t1.[season]>=2017 
AND 
    t1.[runner] IN 
    (
      SELECT TOP 4 runner FROM [league] as t11 
           INNER JOIN [Categories] as t12 
           ON t11.category = t12.category 
         WHERE t11.evIndex=t1.evIndex 
             AND t11.clubID=t1.ClubID 
             AND t12.CategoryGroupID=t2.CategoryGroupID 
         ORDER BY ClubPoints DESC, runner DESC
    ) 
ORDER BY t1.evIndex, t1.ClubID, t2.CategoryGroupID, t1.ClubPoints DESC
```

The above query produce the points per club according to the top 4 results per category-group per event. When I run the above query I get the expected results.
Now I would like to execute a pivot table from the above results

```
TRANSFORM sum(ClubPoints) SELECT ClubID FROM qGetClubPoints GROUP BY ClubID PIVOT evIndex
```

However, I get an error of:

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 't1.evIndex' as a valid field name or expression

It looks as the internal parameters in the query such as `t11.evIndex=t1.evIndex` is not recognized when the query is used as a source for the pivot table.

Comment: I can replicate this behavior under Access 2016 (probably the optimizer acting up, have had problems with it previously). However, short from wrapping that `WHERE` query in a user-defined function, I can't think of a fix. If you're interested in how to do that, I can show you.

Comment: I'm running the query via ASP.NET site, I'm not sure I'll be able to use user-defined function here

Comment: No, unfortunately, you won't. The alternative is to move your `IN` clause to the `FROM` clause and join it in, and the `WHERE` clause from your `IN` clause to the `ON` clause. (you will probably have to go for a nested subquery to be able to use `TOP`, and I'm not 100% sure it's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try writing the "qGetClubPoints" record set to a table; and then applying your pivot query to this table.

ugly but might work

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly what I have ended up doing. As the values do not change often (once/twice per month), whenever it is recalculated it pushes the end results of the query into a table to be the source for the cross-tab. Bummer !!!

Comment: well the use of a scratch pad temp table isn't the worse thing in the world... in some tricky designs, such as yours - it often is the only way.  one nice thing is the visibility of your data in that temp table can help be a test point to see results mid stream....